# In Spring Security, why does SecurityExpressionRoot#isAuthenticated only check !isAnonymous?

Tags: java, spring-security

When configuring web security and specifying something like `.anyRequest().authenticated()`, behind the scenes Spring will eventually invoke `SecurityExpressionRoot.isAuthenticated()` on the request. The instance of `SecurityExpressionRoot` has a field that is pointed to the current `Authentication` instance associated with the request.

The implementation of `SecurityExpressionRoot.isAuthenticated()` looks like this:

```java
@Override
public final boolean isAuthenticated() {
  return !isAnonymous();
}
```

What I don't understand is why it's not invoking `this.authentication.isAuthenticated()` instead. `SecurityExpressionRoot`'s `isAnonymous()` method is also public, and in my mind `isAuthenticated()` and `isAnonymous()` don't seem like logical opposites to one another (i.e. just because you're not authenticated, perhaps due to an expired session, doesn't seem like it automatically implies we don't know who the user is).

I'm guessing there are greater implications around what anonymous implies in the greater Spring Security taxonomy, but I don't know what they are and haven't found anything in the docs yet. Hoping someone could tell me why it's correct that this method doesn't simply invoke `this.authentication.isAuthenticated()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have some reasons that I remember now:

1. Authentication can be null, therefore a
   `NullPointerException` may occur.
2. Users can provide an `AuthenticationTrustResolver` of their own and customize what `isAnonymous` means.
3. You could have a custom type of `Authentication`, let's say `MultiFactorAuthentication`, to identify that you have not finished MFA authentication yet, and this authentication might be anonymous. You have provided your credentials, `isAuthenticated = true`, but the authentication process is not finished. [See this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/authentication/username-password/mfa/src/main/java/example/MfaTrustResolver.java).

Those methods are `public` but they are `final`, you can't override them. Instead, you have to customize the `AuthenticationTrustResolver`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marcus. I did see the `AuthenticationTrustResolver` type and started to fiddle with that, but I felt like I was wading into waters I shouldn't be in. As it turns out I am actually using a custom type of `Authentication` and part of the problem I hit was that there was a disconnect between `authenticated()` on the web security builder and what I was doing. I'm returning `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` now and it works, but that's what sparked this question as I assumed `false` on my `Authentication` type should have worked.